# Show that a is irreducible if and only if the principal ideal (a) is maximal in the set {(b) | b a nonzero nonunit in R}.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a domain and $a$ a nonzero nonunit in R. Show that $a$ is irreducible if and only if the principal ideal (a) is maximal in the set {($b$) where $b$ a nonzero nonunit in R}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(a)$ is not maximal in the given set, there is $b$, a nonzero nonunit,  such that $(a)\subsetneq (b)$, which means $a=rb$ for some $r\in R$.  So $a$ is reducible.

The converse is equally straight forward.   I leave it to you.

Comment: why is r necessarily not a unit in this case?

Comment: If $r$ is a unit, we get $b=r^{-1}a$, which implies $(b)\subset (a)$, contradicting our assumption.